# How to upload xls file to sql server based on ID

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, xls

I have enquiry on how to `insert` the `xls` file to `SQL Server` through a upload button.

I have an existing table in `SQL Server` which consist of column

> `sno(id)`, `customername`, `customeridentity`, `detail`.

The column `sno`, `customername`, and `customeridentity` already been filled, just left with the detail `xls` that need to be uploaded by others through a upload button on the selected row.

How can I `insert` the `xls` file to `SQL Server` by `ID`?

My code

```
Protected Sub DataUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim filepath As String = "C:\New folder\" + XXUpload.UploadedFiles.ToArray(0).FileName.ToString + ".xls"
    Dim con, con1 As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd, cmd1 As New OleDbCommand
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xx;Initial Catalog=xx;User Id=xx;Password=xx;Provider=SQLNCLI10"

    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con

     cmd.CommandText = "Update RequestClip Set Detail = @details Where sno IN(Select sno from RequestClip); "
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@details", filepath)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

    ClipGrid.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Expected output

```
sno     customername   customeridentity       detail
  1             john                  1      123.xls  
  2              max                  2      223.xls
```

Comment: Where to begin..

Comment: where to begin?

Comment: If a record has already been added with the 3 columns then you need an Update statement. `Update RequestClip Set detail = @details Where sno = @sno;` Then add the parameters to the command.

Comment: Are you trying to add a string with a path to the excel file or the file itself as a BLOB or the data in the file?

Comment: i am trying to add the excel file itself to the sql server, basically different row different excel file.

Comment: Your revised update statement will set every row in the table to have the same file path. You should also decide if you're storing the file path in the table, or the contents of the file (as bytes) cos right now you seem to be saying that you want to store the bytes, but your code is storing the path. I'd recommend you store the path, and keep the files on disk. Databases aren't for storing file data (they can, but in 100% of cases I know of where it's been done, the decision is later regretted)

Comment: you are right, i have done it in another way like this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489907/how-to-upload-xls-files-data-to-sql-server-in-devexpress-popup-control/52490068?noredirect=1#comment91924900_52490068 , the new problem is stated in the post (Edit 2*)